# Different results for having with subquery between MySQL 5.7 and 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

For query:

```
SELECT
  MIN(main_table.id) as id,
  COALESCE(used_options.used, 0)           AS used,
  COALESCE(forced_options.force_option, 0) AS force_option
FROM main_table
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                used_options.id id,
                1 AS            used
              FROM main_table AS used_options
              WHERE used_options.id = 20
            ) AS used_options
    ON used_options.id = main_table.id
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                test.id,
                1 AS force_option
              FROM main_table AS test
              WHERE test.id = 10
            ) AS forced_options
    ON forced_options.id = main_table.id
 GROUP BY main_table.id
 HAVING (used IS NOT NULL AND used > 0)
    OR (force_option IS NOT NULL AND force_option = 1);
```

On MySQL 5.7.19 (docker image mysql:5.7.19) I get:

```
+-----+------+--------------+
| id  | used | force_option |
+-----+------+--------------+
|   1 |    0 |            0 |
|   2 |    0 |            0 |
|   3 |    0 |            0 |
|   4 |    0 |            0 |
|   5 |    0 |            0 |
|   6 |    0 |            0 |
|  10 |    0 |            1 |
|  20 |    1 |            0 |
+-----+------+--------------+
```

On MySQL 5.6.37 (docker image mysql:5.6.37) I get:

```
+-----+------+--------------+
| id  | used | force_option |
+-----+------+--------------+
|  10 |    0 |            1 |
|  20 |    1 |            0 |
+-----+------+------+------+--------------+
```

Sample data to create and fill the table:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table
(
     id   INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     fk_1 INT         NOT NULL,
     fk_2 VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO main_table (id, fk_1, fk_2) VALUES (1, 1, '2');
INSERT INTO main_table (id, fk_1, fk_2) VALUES (2, 1, '4');
INSERT INTO main_table (id, fk_1, fk_2) VALUES (3, 1, '5');
INSERT INTO main_table (id, fk_1, fk_2) VALUES (4, 1, '7');
INSERT INTO main_table (id, fk_1, fk_2) VALUES (5, 1, '10');
INSERT INTO main_table (id, fk_1, fk_2) VALUES (6, 1, '20');
INSERT INTO main_table (id, fk_1, fk_2) VALUES (10, 1, '34');
INSERT INTO main_table (id, fk_1, fk_2) VALUES (20, 1, '23');
```

What was changed between those two version of MySQL? It looks like `HAVING` clause is ignored in newer version for this particular query.

There was some BC in this area?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but... why are you using GROUP BY and HAVING in the first place? Normally you would use this only in case you have any aggregation functions (like SUM, MIN, MAX, etc). I would suggest replacing the last 2 lines of your query with `WHERE used > 0 OR force_option = 1`

Comment: @Verma I agree with you about ```GROUP BY```. This query is the simplest example of the issue with I encountered. I changed my query according to your suggestion and I doesn't work.

Comment: appears to work on MySQL 5.6 ... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28a980/2/0

Comment: @Verma Yes, it works on MySQL 5.6, but I don't know why the behavior was changed on 5.7.

Comment: It is something of a moot point why you got either result set, because your query is invalid according to ANSI standards.  Just turn on `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and leave it on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the crux of the problem:

```
GROUP BY main_table.id
```

You are grouping by one column but selecting many non aggregate columns:

```
SELECT
    main_table.id,
    main_table.fk_2,
    main_table.fk_1,
    COALESCE(used_options.used, 0)           AS used,
    COALESCE(forced_options.force_option, 0) AS force_option
```

The issue here is that it is not clear *which* values for `used` and `force_option` are being used for each `id`.

I propose that, despite what you are seeing, MySQL actually used non zero values for `used` and `force_option` values of `1` when computing each `id` group for the query which ran on MySQL 5.7.19.  For the query which ran on MySQL 5.6.37, this did not happen, and the `HAVING` clause filtered off all but two records, which is what we would expect by glancing at the table data.

The real culprit here is MySQL's `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode, which, when turned off, allows such lax queries selecting non aggregate columns which also use `GROUP BY`.  The best long term fix would be for you to refactor your query such that you don't need to select non aggregate columns.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: I added ```ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY``` to MySQL configuration. Also I removed columns ```fk_2``` and ```fk_1```. Change first column in ```SELECT``` clause to ```MIN(main_table.id) as id```. But still I got this same results on MySQL 5.7.19. I resolved this issue by refactor my query, but I looking for some documentation explanation why this was changed.

Comment: @ZbigniewPretki If you enabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to your query as you have pasted above then it should have failed.  If it ran, then you did not enable this flag.  Note that there does not even need to be a documented change for this.  If you don't tell MySQL which record from a group to choose, then it is free to do whatever it wants, at least in principle.